# knockout css binding to table selected row

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockout bindings and javascript

```
<table id="tblall" border="0" class="table table-hover" width="100%">
<tbody data-bind="foreach: myinfo">
<tr id="Tr1" style="cursor: pointer" > 
 <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectIt, css: { 'red': $parent.isSelected == $data } "></td>
<td data-bind="text: $parent.isSelected"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and this javascript

```
function (logger, system, router) {
var isSelected = ko.observable();
---
---
-
--
    var vm = {
             isSelected:isSelected,
        selectit: function(row, event) {

               isSelected(row.id);

            }
```

when I select a row it is changing the isselected but the css never changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's the comparison

```
$parent.isSelected == $data
```

`$data` is going to contain a `myinfo` object, whatever that looks like

You're not binding an array of strings to the table are you?